# Meta tags not chanigng Facebook Like and Share diaglos

Tags: facebook

Would be glad if you tell me if it was successfully resolved on SO...

I included Like and Share buttons on my site, here's the code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://chaoschallenge.org?caption=Oppa!" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

I want to chamge content which is automatically appears in like and share dialog (basically, normal-sized picture and another descrition).

The 'sharer.php' solution seems outdated. The meta tags I took from various sources, doesn't change the dialogs (with appropriate appID)

```
<meta property="fb:app_id"          content="1234567890" /> 
<meta property="og:type"            content="social-cookbook:recipe" /> 
<meta property="og:url"             content="http://samples.ogp.me/136756249803614" /> 
<meta property="og:title"           content="Chocolate Pecan Pie" /> 
<meta property="og:image"           content="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.2178-6/851565_496755187057665_544240989_n.jpg" /> 
<meta property="cookbook:author"    content="http://samples.ogp.me/390580850990722" />
```

screenshot:

[image: Like dialog]

Comment: try https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to see what actually facebook sees. Use debug tool between your changes otherwise Facebook shows you the cached info the first time it fetched that url.

Comment: @tsilik_ Thanks, I see that meta tags changes are reflected in the debugger. Is it because of lag they are not shown in button dialogs?

Comment: Ok, seems like after long lag the data is renewed.